# 2 Mirrors at 90 degrees

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection

In such a case (where the observer is directly behind the object) would the observer be able to see the object? I don't see how it is possible to still see the object, given that the light ray would have to be reflected off the crease for this to work.

I am assuming that the ray of light cannot be reflected on the crease.
[image]

Comment: Surely the object being in the way is a bigger obstacle than the crease...?

Comment: Rather than drawing point object, draw a larger object. You will be able to see it!

Comment: @Matt that question has been closed

Comment: @john It is. Stackexchange does this neat thing where flagging a question as a duplicate automatically generates that comment regardless of whether or not there are answers on the linked question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The observer can see the object in the mirrors on either side of the crease. The crease itself is an infinitely thin line (if the mirrors touch) which will only obscure an object if it is infinitely small.

In the picture below, you can see the reflection of the yellow ball. There is a line down the middle where the crease is, but the ball is still perfectly visible.

[image: Two mirrors at 90 degrees]